# Getting warning in console ag-grid: invalid colDef property 'sortable'

Tags: ag-grid

I am getting a warning message on console while trying to use the colDef property 'sortable'

I am working in 
Angular 6

Comment: Instead of 'sortable' use 'suppressSorting' property and also set 'enableSorting' to **true** in gridOptions

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. But I just updated  the grid to 20.0.0. That was introduced in 20.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not enough information to give an answer, what's the warning?

the property colDef.sortable came out in version 20, maybe you are using an older version of ag-Grid?

Comment: Hi Niall, 
Thanks a lot. 

You are right. Just updated the version as my work is on starting phase.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this warning as well.
My version:

```
"ag-grid-angular": "20.2.0",
"ag-grid-community": "20.2.0",
```

Most likely bug in ag-grid

Comment: Using sortable: true in column definition solved the issue in ag grid 20th versions